Get list of CUPS printers with drivers
For a client's machine that run Oracle Linux 8, I had configured a few dozen printers in CUPS over the past two years. Most of them are installed in remote offices.
I would search and download the appropriate PPD and install with commands such as
lpadmin -p W13Printer1 -v smb://printer:printer@192.168.164.2/HPLaser -o PageSize=A4 -L "Warehouse 13" -P HP-LaserJet_P1102w.ppd

Now I am trying to migrate the applications to a new server and need to recreate the printers config there but don't know which PPD I had used for which printer. If I use lpstat -l -p W13Printer it shows me:
...
Interface: /etc/cups/ppd/W13Printer1.ppd
...

So, should I copy this PPD to the new server and use it to define a new printer?
Also, the interface is shown only for individual printers. How can I get it to show for all printers?
